# iterate in form fields using jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose i have form and it has many form fields. how can i iterate with in all form fields and check the input type and collect the value

my form fields are

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label class="left">
                    First Name
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="FirstName" runat="server" /></li>
            <li>
                <label class="left">
                    Last Name
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="LastName" runat="server" /></li>
            <li>
                <label class="left">
                    Email
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="Email" runat="server" /></li>
            <li>
                <label class="left">
                    Phone
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="Phone" runat="server" /></li>
            <li>
                <label class="left">
                    Contact Method
                </label>
                <span class="checkBoxGroup">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ReqEmail" runat="server" /><label>Email</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ReqMail" runat="server" /><label>Mail</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ReqPhone" runat="server" /><label>Phone</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ReqNoContact" runat="server" /><label>No Contact</label>
                </span></li>
            <li>
                <label class="left">
                    New Letter Type
                </label>
                <span class="myGroupRandom" >
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" runat="server" /><label>Company News</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2" runat="server" /><label>Press Releases</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox3" runat="server" /><label>Deals</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox4" runat="server" /><label>Employement</label>
                </span></li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" /></li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</form>
```

please guide thanks

Comment: What's the end goal, why do you want to check the element's type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each($("input"), function(index, item) {
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
    var val = $(this).val();
    //do your checking...
    if (type == "text") {
        //and so on...
    }
});
```

Note that I use `$(this)` to access the item, rather than the `item` parameter argument - using `item` might not cause an issue when working with only `input` elements, but I have had trouble in the past when accessing properties and methods of an element using the `item`, so generally resort to `$(this)`.