# jQuerymobile validating the field values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

My `jQuerymobile` + `PhoneGap` app I have a page with 20 field items, I'm trying to validate some of it's fields as below:

```
function validate() {
    if ($('#username').val() == '') {

        alert("Fullname Required")
    }
    if ($('#email').val() == '') {

        alert("Email Required")
    }
    if ($('#digitalspend').has('option').length > 0) {

        alert("Digital media Spend Required")
    }
    if ($('#objective1').has('option').length > 0) {

        alert("objective1 Required")
    }
    if ($('#objective2').has('option').length > 0) {

        alert("objective2 Required")
    }
    if ($('#objective3').has('option').length > 0) {

        alert("objective3 Required")
    }
    if ($('#name').val() == '') {

        alert("Organization Name Required")
    } else {

        loadingStart();
        setTimeout(function () {
            loadingEnd();
            $.mobile.changePage('#page2');
        }, 5000);
        return false;

        function loadingStart() {
            $.mobile.loading('show', {
                text: "Please Wait...",
                textVisible: true,
                theme: 'b',

            });
        }

        function loadingEnd() {
            $.mobile.loading("hide");
        }

    }
}
```

I want to validate this fields and if everything is filled.
I need to show the loading dialogue and go to next page. But it is not working as expected. Instead of alert statement I want to validate whole form once not field by field.

Comment: Please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7203722/2410252. I think it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, I recommend the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

This plugin lets you define rules for each field you want to validate. Upon validation, it labels each field with your predefined message if it doesn't meet the requirements .

Have a look at this example from the [demo page](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/):

```
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            topic: {
                required: "#newsletter:checked",
                minlength: 2
            },
            agree: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
            lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
            username: {
                required: "Please enter a username",
                minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            agree: "Please accept our policy"
        }
    });
```